# Fatal error after installling Kiwicommerce SMTP extension

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Source class "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP" for "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP\Logger" generation does not exist. in /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(124): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('\\KiwiCommerce\\E...', Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Profiler\Code\Generator\Logger)) #1 /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(213): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('\\KiwiCommerce\\E...') #2 /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(124): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('KiwiCommerce\\En...', Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Profiler\Code\Generator\Logger)) #3 /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('KiwiCommerce\\En...') #4 [internal function]: in /home/ksantosh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 218
```

Comment: try these command from ssh in magento root `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: when i exute this command it shows me an error say :- Source class "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP" for "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP\Logger" generation does not exist

Answer (score 0):

run following commands in same order:

sudo rm -rf  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media

Let me know if still have an issue

Comment: when i exute this command it shows me an error say :- Source class "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP" for "\KiwiCommerce\EnhancedSMTP\Logger" generation does not exist